# Unable to change enumerable attribute inside JSON.stringify replacer function?

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to serialize non enumerable properties inside the replacer function.

What is wrong here?

help please.

```
var obj = {x:1,y:2};
Object.defineProperty(obj,"x",{enumerable:false});


var s = JSON.stringify(obj,function(key,value){
if(this.propertyIsEnumerable(key) == false){
Object.defineProperty(this,key,{enumerable:true});
}
return value;});

//"{"y":2}"
// x remains not enumerable
```

I guess non enumerable properties is being filtered out before the execution of replacer function. Not sure.

Comment: If `.stringify` filters out non-enumerable properties, then yes, they aren't available in the callback - it has already done that filter. Why don't you just loop through all the keys of the object before you stringify, `for (key in obj)`, and use your logic inside to set it as enumerable if it isn't already. Then, just simply call `JSON.stringify(obj);`

Comment: well, for in loop doesn't include non enumerable properties :)

Comment: Ahh yes, well that would make sense! So what kinds of things aren't set as `enumerable` that you want to include in the serialization?

Comment: It isn't fully supported, but this seems to let you enumerate over all properties: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames

Comment: Thanks got it, Kindly post in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `.stringify` filters out non-enumerable properties, then yes, they aren't available in the callback - it has already done that filter. Why don't you just loop through all the keys of the object before you stringify, and use your logic inside to set it as enumerable if it isn't already. Then, just simply call `JSON.stringify(obj);`. Unfortunately as you pointed out, `for in` loops and jQuery's `$.each` does not loop over non-enumerable keys. I found that `.getOwnPropertyNames` should accomplish what you want - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames

Here's an example of using it, similar to your code you provided:

http://jsfiddle.net/9Em82/

```
var obj = {x:1,y:2};

Object.defineProperty(obj,"x",{enumerable:false});

var all = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj);
for (var i = 0, j = all.length; i < j; i++) {
    console.log("KEY: " + all[i]);
}
```